# Besides MVC and HMVC, what other designs are there for high level application design?

Tags: architecture

So far whenever I am planning the design for an application, I always find myself falling back to MVC or HMVC after a few iterations of prototyping and testing. Are there any other application design patterns which are commonly used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although closely related to MVC there is also [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) (Model View ViewModel) which is Microsoft's recommended pattern for WPF applications.

Answer (score 0):

Although not comprehensive, this might be of help:

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/general/a-beginners-guide-to-design-patterns/